# How to use Session variable object in foreach-MVC5 View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working on dynamic menus. Using Session Variable by passing whole object. As can be seen from controller:

```
Session["PackageSbMenu2"] = QueryHelper.Get_Menu("Manage Services", 3).ToList();
```

**In view:**

```
@foreach(var t in (Session["PackageSbMenu2"]))
{ 
    <li><a href=@Html.ActionLink(t.Controller, t.Action)>t.Name</a></li>
}
```

**QueryHelper Fuction which is responsible of getting data:**

```
public static List<MenusDM> Get_Menu(string name, int ParentMenuId)
{
    AutosLoanDbContext context = new AutosLoanDbContext();
    var menues = from parent in context.MenuInRole
     join child in context.Menu on parent.MenuId equals child.MenuId
     where child.Name == name && child.ParentMenuId == ParentMenuId
                 select child;
    return menues.ToList();
}
```

The error I am getting is:

> foreach statement cannot operate on variable of type object because object doesn't contain a public definition for GetEnumerator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to cast your Session object

```
 @{    
    var menu = Session["PackageSbMenu2"] as List<MenusDM>;
    if(menu != null)
    {
        foreach(var t in menu)
        { 
         <li><a href=@Html.ActionLink(t.Controller, t.Action)>t.Name</a></li>
        }
    }
}
```