# Access Array declared in C# Controller in Razor

Tags: c#, arrays, razor, multidimensional-array

I have a 2D Array declared in my MVC Controller, and I need to access this via Razor so I can loop through each value.

I create a session and set it as the array, but I can't figure out how to access the array through razor.

Controller:

```
string[,] Things = new string[,] {
            { "thing1", "pie" },
            { "thing1", "cake" },
            { "thing1", "potato" }
        };

public void GetThings()
{
    Session["Things"] = Things;
}

public ActionResult Index()
{
    GetThings();
    return View();
}
```

Razor:

```
@{
    for (int i = 0; i < Session["Things"].GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        @i
    }
}
```

I get the error "'object' does not contain a definition for `Getlength`, the only suggested actions are `.Equals`, `.GetHashCode`, `.GetType`, and `.ToString`.

The above c# in the razor works if I declare the array within the razor, replacing "Session..." with the array variable name.

I can't read any values from the array session to display on the HTML front end, doing `@Session["Things"]` displays `System.String[,]` in browser (but then this is the same as if I tried to call the array declared in razor), `@Session["Things"][1,1]` gives browser error

> Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'

Comment: Session holds `object`s not strongly typed, hence the error "Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Session variable object in foreach-MVC5 View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29745379/how-to-use-session-variable-object-in-foreach-mvc5-view)

Comment: Why would you use a session for this?

Comment: @ErikPhilips I chose to use a session as this array needs to be used in multiple places not just in the razor front end, such as other functions in the controller and called through a get to JS (as JSON), and I didn't want to have to repeat this array in multiple places. This way means I have one master list I need to manage, and couldn't think of a better way to declare the array once and have it accessible by all areas that need it. If theres a better way please let me know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast to array:

```
((string[,])Session["Things"]).GetLength(0)
```